# Importing openCV in python idle error: shared object file

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi3, python-idle

I have been trying to use the cv2 library in python (in IDLE on raspberry pi 3) but I can't manage to import it successfully.

when I type import cv2, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/python/test.py", line 2, in <module>
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libjasper .so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have used the terminal to update, upgrade, and install opencv along with pretty much every other thing I could find relating to opencv or lib. I currently can import cv2 in the terminal but not in IDLE. What do I need to do to be able to import the cv2 library? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibility 1: you have more than one Python installed on the system.  Possibility 2: the '.' in '.cv2' makes the import relative to a starting point that is different in the two scenarios.  It can depends on the startup methods and mode (interactive versus batch), which affect the current working directory.   Adding `import os; print(os.getcwd())` before `import .cv2` might reveal something.

Answer (score 6):

Recommended way of installing opencv on linux as given by opencv docs "https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html" for python3 is:

```
sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

for python2:

```
sudo apt install python-opencv
```

On Raspberry pi you may occasionally need to run:

```
sudo apt update --fix-missing
```

It will auto-install all the dependencies.

Comment: Works perfectly on RPi4 with OpenCV 4.3.0

Answer (score 5):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/amymcgovern/pyparrot/issues/34), below installations seemed to resolve the issue. It worked for me.

```
pip3 install opencv-python
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev
sudo apt-get install libqtgui4
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
sudo apt-get install libqt4-test
```

Or

the newer OpenCV version handles other installations themselves.

```
pip install opencv-python==4.1.2.30
```

Comment: Specifying the version when installing with pip Ex. "pip install opencv-python==4.1.2.30" solved for me.

Comment: @Aravinda_gn still you needed the lines below that right? or just the first line with a version number?

Comment: First try only "pip install opencv-python==4.1.2.30" without other lines. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the commands for opencv and face recognition : (it worked for me)

```html
-> sudo apt update

-> sudo apt upgrade

-> sudo apt-get install python3-pip

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 -V
Python 3.5.3
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python2 -V
Python 2.7.13

-> pip3 install numpy

-> pip3 install pillow

-> pip3 install dlib

-> sudo apt-get install cmake

-> pip3 install face_recognition

-> sudo apt-get install python-opencv

-> sudo apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev

-> sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev

-> sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev

-> sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev -y

-> sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev -y

-> sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev -y

-> sudo pip3 install opencv-python

-> sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev libswscale-dev openexr libopenexr-dev

-> sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev

-> sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-0-dbg libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev



pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> import dlib
>>> import face_recognition
>>>
```

Depends on the system. 
for PI will take : 2 to 3 hr. (total time)

thanks :)

Comment: What is the use of install `face-recognition` when the op has only asked to install opencv. You are installing too many packages that why it took you 2 to 3hrs