# OpenCV import on Raspberry Pi 4 not working

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am experiencing a lot of trouble installing OpenCV for my Raspberry Pi 4 running rasbian full.
I believe i have installed the package correctly but I am having this error:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_fetch_add_8
```

I have a competition soon and need to get it done fast.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undefined symbol: \_\_atomic\_fetch\_add\_8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58778865/undefined-symbol-atomic-fetch-add-8)

Comment: yes, its that error.... what do I do?

Comment: Read that answer...